# Struct with protocol as property type does not conform to protocols 'Decodable' and 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, codable, decodable, encodable

I have a struct `UISectionModel` with only one property `section`, which has a protocol `UISectionProtocol` for a type, as follows:

```
struct UISectionModel: Codable {
    let section: UISectionProtocol
}
```

Here is the implementation of the `UISectionProtocol` protocol:

```
protocol UISectionProtocol: Codable {
    var identifier: String? { get }
}
```

As you can see, I need `UISectionModel` to conform to the `Codable` protocol, but I keep getting an error stating that it does not conform to neither `Decodable` or `Encodable`, even though the only property's type is already conforming to `Codable`. I suspect it has to do with the fact that this type is a protocol, but I can't figure the exact reason that is causing the error to appear or how to fix it.

Would appreciate some insight!

I tried replacing the type of `section` with an enum that conforms to `UISectionProtocol`:

```
struct UISectionModel: Codable {
    let section: UIDefaultSection
}

enum UIDefaultSection: UISectionProtocol {
    case imageSection(section: UIImageSection)
    case labelSection(section: UILabelSection)
    
    var identifier: String? {
        switch self {
        case .imageSection(let section): return section.identifier
        case .labelSection(let section): return section.identifier
        }
    }
}
```

This made the error go away, but I'm thinking that `section` needs to be of any type that conforms to `UISectionProtocol`, instead of being limited only to `UIDefaultSection`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you probably believe that saying

```
protocol UISectionProtocol: Codable
```

means that UISectionProtocol conforms to Codable. it doesn't. A protocol does not conform to a protocol. You probably want a generic:

```
struct SectionModel<T: SectionProtocol>: Codable {
    let section: T
}

protocol SectionProtocol: Codable {
    var identifier: String? { get }
}
```

(Note that I have stripped the illegal UI prefix off your type names; that prefix belongs to Apple alone.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you experienced is caused by protocols that don't conform to Codable. When you include a UISectionProtocol field in your UISectionModel struct, the compiler cannot guarantee that all conforming types are also Codable.
To fix this problem you can make UISectionModel generic and add a type constraint to ensure the section property is also codable. Here is an updated version of your code. I think this may solve your issue.

```
protocol UISectionProtocol: Codable {
    var identifier: String? { get }
}
struct UISectionModel<T: UISectionProtocol>: Codable where T: Codable {
    let section: T
}

struct MySection: UISectionProtocol, Codable {
    var identifier: String?
}
```

Comment: Same as what I said.

Comment: I think this is the solution to his problem. Apologies for the answer, as it got similar to yours.